# Integral $\int \frac{x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

I have taken $(x^4+x^2+1)=u$ to differentiate it w.r.t. $x$ to get
$$\int \frac{x}{2u(2x^2+1)}\ du$$

Comment: @Shuri2060 let me try!

Comment: The problem with your substitution is that you haven't gotten rid of all the $x$'s. When doing substitution, you should (almost) always strive to get rid of every trace of the old variable.

Comment: Try $u=x^2$ instead.

Answer (score 4):

$$((x^2+1)+x)((x^2+1) -x) = x^4 + 2x^2 + 1 - x^2 = x^4 + x^2 + 1$$

Then use partial fraction method.

**Edit**: More hints,

$$((x^2+1)+x) + ((x^2+1) -x) = 2(x^2+1)$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{a^2+x^2} = \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$$

Comment: Messiah

Answer (score 4):

$$\dfrac{2x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^4+x^2+1}+\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}$$

$$=\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2+1+\dfrac1{x^2}}+\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2+1+\dfrac1{x^2}}$$

For the first integral:

As $\displaystyle\int\left(1+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)dx=x-\dfrac1x,$

write $x^2+1+\dfrac1{x^2}=1+\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2$

Can you handle the second integral?

Comment: Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$, [Glasser's Master Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GlassersMasterTheorem.html) allows a rapid evaluation:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{x^4+x^2+1}\stackrel{\text{parity}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+3}\stackrel{\text{G.M.T}}{=}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2+3}=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}}.$$

Comment: What was this? Shouldn't it be in terms of x

Comment: @user126358: I said *if you're interested in the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$* (that I believe to be the original task), then ...

Comment: Oh! Sorry Btw Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**By decomposition:**

$$\frac{4x^2}{x^4+x^2+1}=\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}-\frac{2x}{x^2+x+1}
\\=\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}+\frac1{(x-\frac12)^2+\frac34}-\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x+1}+\frac1{(x+\frac12)^2+\frac34}.$$

The corresponding antiderivatives are

$$\log(x^2\pm x+1)$$ and $$\sqrt{\tfrac43}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\tfrac43}(x\pm\tfrac12)\right).$$